# What is the inuition behind the radiation view factor reciprocity?

Tags: heat-transfer, radiation

I have known that the view factor reciprosity is that

Ai x Fij = Aj x Fji

But i can't intuitively explain the logic behind this, i do know that the view factor Fij is the portion of the radiation emitted by surface i that is recieved by surface j

I have looked up for the proof but that doesn't seem to help much

Thank you

Comment: I haven't found a good, physically intuitive explanation either.  What i do know is that if you consider the double area integral definition of the view factor, $F_{ij}A_{i}$ produces the exact same integral as $F_{ji}A_{j}$ because the order of integration is reversible.

Answer (score -1):

It follows from the zeroth law of thermodynamics.

If the two surfaces are at the same temperature, there is no net heat transfer between them, otherwise the temperature of one would rise and the other would fall.

See http://web.mit.edu/16.unified/www/FALL/thermodynamics/notes/node137.html

Comment: After reading the posted link, your response makes some sense. But as a stand-alone answer, it is very ambiguous how this fact leads to reciprocity. Your answer should make this connection more explicit.